# Custom content sharing on facebook

Tags: facebook, customization

I am working on a share button on facebook. I want it to display a custom message in the description of the content sharing but I am unable to do so. Below is the code that I am working on,

```
<script>function fbs_click() {

    u=location.href;t=document.title;
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
    return false;
    }
</script>
<style> html .fb_share_button { 
   display: -moz-inline-block; 
   display:inline-block;
   padding:1px 20px 0 5px; 
   height:15px;
   border:1px solid #d8dfea;
   background:url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat top right;
 } 
html .fb_share_button:hover {
    color:#fff;
    border-color:#295582; 
    background:#3b5998 url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat top right; 
    text-decoration:none; 
} 
</style> <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;www.adsterr.com>" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Share</a>
```

Please help me out with the values of `u`,`t` and other parameters so I can make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook share button has been deprecated, you can read it here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

Instead of that you can either use one of the social plugins:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/ (such as the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), [Send Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) or the  [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)) or open the facebook dialogs yourself using the facebook javascript sdk: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/